# Toggling between Unity 3D and unity 2D

Tags: unity, bash, unity-2d, scripts

Generally, I much prefer Unity 3D over the 2D version, which is a bit broken on my machine. However, I frequently give presentations, and Compiz doesn't support multiple screens. I've been forced to log out of 3D and into 2D every time I give a presentation, then back to 3D afterwards to get a more usable desktop.

To avoid this inconvenience, I've written a script to toggle between Unity 2D and 3D without requiring a logout. Unfortunately, when I run it from 2D, I wind up with 3D running, *plus* the 2D panel and launcher. Both are on the screen simultaneously. I suspect that the 2D processes I'm killing are getting re-spawned somehow. Can someone help me debug my script?

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

unity_2d="unity-2d-places unity-2d-launcher unity-2d-panel unity-2d-spread"

start_2d() {
  metacity --replace &
  for i in $unity_2d; do
    "$i" &
  done
}

stop_2d() {
  killall $unity_2d  # The lack of quotes around $unity_2d is deliberate.
}

start_3d() {
  unity --replace &
}

stop_3d() {
  : # no-op for now
}

if ps -u "$USER" | grep -q [m]etacity; then
  # Unity 2D is currently running.
  stop_2d
  start_3d
else
  # Unity 3D is currently running.
  stop_3d
  start_2d
fi
```

## Edit

My script works when I log in to 3D. It doesn't work when I log in to 2D. So, it works for my most common use case, but the fact that it fails the other way around suggests to me that I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Hi, I am not a script writer but I do get crazy ideas. This script works from 3D to 2D but not the other way around. Perhaps you need two scripts. Create a second script by switching the 2D and 3D references around and see if this second script works when you are logged into 2D and want to switch to 3d. I am sorry if this is a stupid idea. Regards.

Comment: @graham: What would the second script do that the first one doesn't do already?

Comment: As far as I can tell, my script isn't buggy or anything. It seems to be doing what it was told to do. The problem seems to be that I'm missing a step or two. Switching the order of things won't add the missing step.

Comment: This question never got a good answer, and since 11.10 removes my need for this script, I'm trying to close this question.

Comment: How does 11.10 removes the need for the script? And by the way, regardless of Natty or Oneiric, you can move from 2D to 3D with a simple `unity --replace`.

Comment: @Oxwivi: At least in Natty, moving from 2D to 3D isn't that simple. If you do a `unity --replace`, you'll wind up with two launchers and two panels. Try it and see. My problem with this script was that I was unable to make the 2D launcher and panel go away; even when killed, they simply respawned. However, in Oneiric, 2D is sufficiently functional that I don't go insane trying to work around its limitations, and Oneiric finally explained why I couldn't connect a projector while running Compiz and suggested a workaround.

Comment: Actually, as much as I'd like it, 3D doesn't work on my hardware. It did work if I forced started 3D in Natty sans launcher icons. And from that experience I say `unity --replace` cleanly killed Unity 2D. Or not, writing this, I realized I only issued the command from GNOME Classic.

Answer (score 0):

When you run metacity --replace, I would expect it to end the Compiz session for you. Hence, perhaps it would help if you did *not* call stop_3d, but just start_2d. It might be the case that you now manually kill 3D, which triggers a restart of Compiz, however, before it is restarted, 2D will launch but think 3D isn't running and, hence, not end it properly (without triggering a restart).

Just a hunch, but you never know.

Comment: stop_3d is a no-op; it does nothing. start_2d seems to work OK. The problem is with stopping *2D*. It's the *2D* stuff that's presumably re-spawning, not compiz.

Comment: See my edit above for additional details.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm blind :S

Could the problem lie in the detection whether Unity 2D is running? (Sorry, it's really just basic debugging but I've got nothing better.)

It _might_ also just be a bug in Unity - does it work when you just run unity --replace from a terminal with 2D running?

Comment: 2D detection is clearly working, else my script wouldn't work from a 3D session. And running `unity --replace` won't get rid of the 2D panel, dock, etc. That's why I'm trying to kill those processes, which are getting re-spawned.

Comment: `unity --replace` should work (according to `unity --help`, running just `unity` should do the same), so I would [report a bug](http://bugs.ubuntu.com) to see if it can get fixed - should make things a lot easier.

Comment: `unity --replace` will replace `metacity`. But Metacity is separate from the 2D panel, etc. Because those are separate processes, they must be separately killed. Think of pre-Unity `gnome-panel`. The reason it works the other way around is that in 3D, the panel, etc. are part of the window manager (Unity, which is built on top of Compiz), so `metacity --replace` kills everything. Metacity has no panel built in.

Comment: Ah OK then, I was expecting it just detecting other window managers and perhaps explicitly support Unity 2D as it's a sibling project.

Anyway, sorry for not really being of any help. Did learn something myself though :)